# Ordinary Differential Equation with imaginary numbers

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a lecture, I was told by the professor that the general solution for this ordinary differential equation in the picture below is as in the second picture. When I did the calculation myself I've found out that β (the module of the imaginary part) was $\sqrt{2}$, so why the lecturer added the x below the radical?

Equation:

$y'' + 2y = 0$

Solution:

$y(x)=k_1 \cos(\sqrt{2x}) + k_2 \sin(\sqrt{2x})$

Comment: probably a typo, $x$ should be outside the radical. also... $\sin$ not $sen$.

Comment: not sure, he went forward doing the math as if x was inside... it's written `sen` because it's in Portuguese :)

Comment: **doing the math as if x was inside.** then let your teacher know they are wrong. $x$ is outside the $\sqrt{} $. May be you'll get extra credit for that.